# AJAX вернуть несколько массивов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли при помощи AJAX вернуть сразу несколько массивов?
Не нашёл решения, подскажите как можно решить такую задачу ? (или всё объединять в один, а потом в JS уже разбивать на столько, сколько нужно?)

Comment: Да, именно так. Сделать массив массивов.

Comment: возможно, более уместным будет объект с полями-массивами.

Comment: @teran я не то что поспорить хочу. Просто не вижу разницы. Почему объект более уместен?

Comment: @KAGGDesign Чтобы обращаться к вложенным массивам, не по индeксам, а по названиям.

Comment: @Igor я имел ввиду ассоциативный массив массивов.

Comment: @KAGGDesign тогда - возражений нет

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите с помощью сервера передать клиенту через запрос по AJAX -у многомерный массив в виде JSON? Или наоборот - от клиента к серверу? Пожалуйста напишите развёрнутый ответ. А то я уже подготовил вам ответ, а теперь засомневался.